# How to flatten dynamic json key into columns in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery, unnest

Here is the original JSON structure:

```
{
    "tt": [{
    "box": {
      "type": "A"
    },
        "rr": {...}
    }, {
    "box": {
      "type": "B"
    },
        "rr": {...}
    }, {
    "box": {
      "type": "C"
    },
        "rr": {...}
    }]
}
```

Then I use the SQL command below to get the `tt` structure

```
with t1 as (
SELECT
  rate_card,
  JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(rate_card, '$.tt') as rr,
FROM `original_table_temp`
)
```

The `rr` JSON structure from the previous JSON structure above looks something like below

```
{
  "rr": {
    "10": {   <-------------------------
      "tils": {
        "mdd": {
          "df": {
            "tif": {
              "sc": 17.85,  <------------------
              "evr": [
                {
                  "p": 16.35,   <---------------------
                  "t": null,
                  "nr?": false
                }
              ]
        }
      }
    },
    "11": {...},
    "12": {...},
    ...
  }
}
```

All the SQL commands above are executed in BigQuery.

I am interested to get the `box.type`, `rr`'s `keys`, which are 10, 11, 12 & so on in `rr` into a column.

The columns next to the `keys` are `sc` & `p`

In the end the output of the table would be as below:

```
+------------+---------+---------------+
| box.type|    rr  |  sc   |     p     |
+------------+-------------------------+
|  A      | 10     | 17.85    |  16.35    |

|  A      | 11     |some value|  ....     |
......

|   C     | 12     |  .....   |     ......|
+------------+----------------------------+
```

At the moment, I managed to get the `sc` value by hard-cording in SQL BigQuery. See below:

```
SELECT
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(rr_2, '$.rr.10.tils.mdd.df.tif.sc') AS sc,
FROM t1,
UNNEST(rr) rr_2
```

The method above is not productive & efficient as there are many `keys` like 10, 11, 12 and so on.

1. How to extract the dynamic `keys` from `rr` into a columns?
2. How to not hard-code the SQL to get `sc` & `p`?

Feel free to remove the `<----------` in the JSON sample when you test your answer.

It is a long post. If you need more information, let me know.

Thanks for your patience & time.

Comment: Your idea of not "hard-coding" would be to try to find the fields `sc` and `p` in the nested structure dynamically ?

Comment: `which is taken from a JSON array column` - I suggest you to show original json with that array - so it will be significantly easier for us to help  you - and also I expect if we start off of that array it will be just super simple solution

Comment: @Isac, yes you are correct. I want to get `sc`, `p` dynamically without the need to write `'$.rr.10.tils.mdd.df.tif.sc'`

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant, I have edited the original question to include the original JSON structure. Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1):

JSON objects with a non-closed set of keys don't map well into a SQL table-oriented domain.

One way to solve this is to transform JSON data structured like `{key1: {}, key2: {}, ...}` into something like `[{key1, ...}, {key2, ...}, ...]`.

Such a transformation can be readily achieved in the Javascript domain using a [BigQuery Javascript UDF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#javascript-udf-structure)...

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION extract_tt(json STRING)
RETURNS STRUCT<
  tt ARRAY<STRUCT<
    box STRUCT<
      type STRING
    >,
    rr ARRAY<STRUCT<
      key STRING,
      tils STRUCT<
        mdd STRUCT<
          df STRUCT<
            tif STRUCT<
              sc FLOAT64,
              evr ARRAY<STRUCT<
                p FLOAT64,
                t STRING,
                nr BOOL
              >>
            >
          >
        >
      >
    >>
  >>
>
DETERMINISTIC
LANGUAGE js
AS
r"""
try {
  return JSON.parse(json,
    (key, value) => {
      if (key === 'rr' && value !== null && typeof value === 'object')
        return Object.keys(value).map(key => ({ key, ...value[key] }));
      else
        return value;
    });
}
catch {}
""";

WITH extracted AS (
  SELECT extract_tt(json).*
  FROM UNNEST([
    '{"tt":[{"box":{"type":"A"},"rr":{"10":{"tils":{"mdd":{"df":{"tif":{"sc":17.85,"evr":[{"p":16.35,"t":null,"nr":false}]}}}}},"11":{}}},{"box":{"type":"B"},"rr":{}},{"box":{"type":"C"},"rr":{"12":{"tils":{"mdd":{"df":{"tif":{"sc":99}}}}}}}]}'
  ]) AS json
)
SELECT box.type, key, tils.mdd.df.tif.sc, tils.mdd.df.tif.evr[OFFSET(0)].p
FROM extracted, UNNEST(tt), UNNEST(rr);
```

Here is the result of unpacking `rr` which can smoothly represent any degree of variation on the dynamic keys of `rr`...

| Row | type | key | sc | p |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 10 | 17.85 | 16.35 |
| 2 | A | 11 | *null* | *null* |
| 3 | C | 12 | 99.0 | *null* |

Note the return type of the UDF was carefully crafted to map from the JSON domain to the SQL domain. As long as the types match, the BigQuery object caster takes care of everything else for you!

Comment: Note that using Javascript UDF's do introduce some performance penalties. If your data is large, you may notice it takes substantially longer to process your data. There is no cost impact however as you're charged for bytes processed, not time.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below

```
execute immediate (
    select string_agg("select " || key || ''' key
    , JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(rr_2, '$.rr.''' || key || '''.tils.mdd.df.tif.sc') AS sc 
    , JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(rr_2, '$.rr.''' || key || '''.tils.mdd.df.tif.evr[0].p') AS p
  from `project.dataset.table`''', " union all ")
  from `project.dataset.table`, unnest(regexp_extract_all(regexp_replace(JSON_EXTRACT(rr_2, '$.rr'), r':{.*?}+', ''), r'"(.*?)"')) key
);
```

If to apply to `rr JSON` structure from  your original example - output is

[image]

Comment: How do I use your answer with ```with t1 as (
SELECT
  rate_card,
  JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(rate_card, '$.tt') as rr,
FROM `original_table_temp`
)```? I got an error message below from Google BigQuery when I use `Execute Immediate`: `Syntax error: Expected "(" or "," or keyword SELECT but got keyword EXECUTE at [38:1]`